# Temporary Tables in Stored Procedures: To Drop or Not To Drop?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I have come across this question quite a few times but have been unable to find an answer that fully satisfies me. Basically, what most people and books say is that "*Although temporary tables are deleted when they go out of scope, you should explicitly delete them when they are no longer needed to reduce resource requirements on the server*".

It is clear to me that when you are working in Management Studio and creating tables, you will use some resources for that table until you close your window or disconnect. Therefore, it is logical to drop the table when it is no longer needed.

However, when you work with a stored procedure, if you want to clean up tables, you will most likely do it at the end of the procedure (I am not talking about situations where you drop the table as soon as you no longer need it in the procedure). So, the workflow would be something like this:

When you drop in the stored procedure:

- Start of stored procedure execution
- Do some work
- Drop tables
- End of execution

And as far as I understand it, how can it possibly work when you do not drop:

- Start of stored procedure execution
- Do some work
- End of execution
- Drop tables

What is the difference here? I can only imagine that some resources are needed to identify the temporary tables. Do you have any other thoughts?

UPDATE:

I ran a simple test with 2 stored procedures:

```
create procedure test  as
begin
create table #temp (a int)
insert into #temp values (1);
drop table #temp;
end
```

and another one without drop statements. I enabled user statistics and ran the tests:

```
declare @i int = 0;
 while @i < 10000
 begin
 exec test;
 SET @i= @i + 1;
 end
```

Here are the results (Trials 1-3 dropping the table in the stored procedure, Trials 4-6 not dropping it):
[image]

As the picture shows, all stats are the same or have decreased slightly when I do not drop the temporary table.

UPDATE2:

I ran this test a second time with 100,000 calls and also added SET NOCOUNT ON. These are the results:
[image]

As the second run confirmed, if you do not drop the table in the stored procedure, you actually save some user time, as this is done by some other internal process outside of the user's time.

Comment: did you consider table variables? http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx With these you do not need to bother about dropping

Comment: You dont *need* to bother dropping temp tables either. Both, under normal circumstances are de-scoped (albeit temp tables, at the statement level, wheras temp tables are tied to the current SPID). Table Variables come with a whole other laundry list of pros and cons though.

Comment: My question is not about  "bothering", my question is about the benefit of dropping them in SP as MSDN and other books are suggesting. @user193655 I am talking about #temp tables

Comment: I've never seen anyone suggest dropping them explicitly in stored procedures. Do you have a link to where on MSDN this is suggested?

Comment: seems I was a bit wrong. I am reading official training materials for sql server 2016 and it is stated there ""Although temporary tables are deleted when they go out of scope, you should explicitly delete them when they are no longer needed to reduce resource requirements on the server""

Comment: I find including a `DROP` can be useful for cases where you want to copy and paste the code out of a proc and run it on its own - but it will be cleaned up (dropped or cached) automatically any way when run in the context of the proc.

Comment: And your test results make sense - that an explicit `DROP` will have to wait for the drop/cache operation to complete. (though deferred drop can happen for large tables) whereas cleanup can happen after the proc finishes executing in the implicit case...

Answer (score 7):

You can read more about in in this Paul White's article: [Temporary Tables in Stored Procedures](https://sqlkiwi.blogspot.com/2012/08/temporary-tables-in-stored-procedures.html)

> CREATE and DROP, Don’t
>
> I will talk about this in much more detail in my next post, but **the
>   key point is that CREATE TABLE and DROP TABLE do not create and drop
>   temporary tables in a stored procedure, if the temporary object can be
>   cached.**  The temporary object is renamed to an internal form when DROP
>   TABLE is executed, and renamed back to the same user-visible name when
>   CREATE TABLE is encountered on the next execution.  In addition, any
>   statistics that were auto-created on the temporary table are also
>   cached.  This means that statistics from a previous execution remain
>   when the procedure is next called.

Comment: While this is something new I learned it is till doesn't answer if there are any performance/space/etc benefits of dropping table at the end of the SP

Comment: Yes it answered. It means that there is no difference at all if you drop or do not drop temporary table within your sp because in any case it will be cached and not dropped at all

Comment: But in that case there is difference as you do not execute actual statement in the stored procedure and most probably it is executed somehow outside it. Most probably that's why in my tests without dropping statistics are slightly better

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is the difference you are talking about. In any case, if you are dropping or not, the table will be renamed and chached, it will happen when you issue explicit drop or when you exit your sp

Comment: What I mean that there is some logic implemented then you or external process do that "DROP" statement. I agree that it doesn't really drops the table, however something is still is done with that table. So when you include drop statement to the SP then it is done using user time, however if you do not do that then it is done by another process which do not affect user time. I hope that my point is clear now. (see UPDATE 2 section in the OP)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, a locally scoped temp table (one with a single hashtag before it) will automatically drop out of scope after your SPID is closed. There are some very odd cases where you get a temp table definition cached somewhere and then no real way to remove it. Usually that happens when you have a stored procedure call which is nested and contains a temp table by the same name.

It's good habit to get into dropping your tables when you're done with them but unless something unexpected happens, they should be de-scoped anyway once the proc finishes.

Comment: I am asking more about performance issues rather than concurrency ones without any nesting.

Comment: Gotcha. Drop is a cheap statement, but not one with no overhead. my guess is if you're calling the procedure as much as you are, the drop probably adds a non-zero amount of time to the proc (dividing !10 batch total by 10000 executions, means you're dropping the table about every 0.6 seconds. If you're really curious, I'd run a profiler trace and see exactly how much time is being allocated to the different parts of your proc as you call it over and over. But it raises a good point. In high volume procs, dropping (or even creating) a temp table may not be the best bang for your buck.